# Datetime issue in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone **please** help with the below?

I am trying to select data from a specific date in Snowflake, and if I cast datetime to date, I am receiving results that go all the way up to the 00:59:59 the following day.

i.e. performing the following in my where clause

`WHERE cast(created_at AS date) = '2023-08-01'`

and what I actually get are results including 2023-08-02 and max datetime of 2023-08-02 00:59:59

Tried casting, convert and format, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what is the type of the datetime column? You might be dealing with the timezone conversion.

Comment: Looks look you're correct - its stored as 'TIMESTAMPTZ'. Any idea how to just get the explicit date from the stamp? The timezone has no significance to my use case...but I need it to not convert the date if that makes sense :-D

Comment: TIMESTAMPTZ stores UTC time plus offset; the default timezone in Snowflake session is Los_Angeles. Your session timezone must match the one in the table. For example, if there is no offset in your table then it would be UTC time. You need to use ```alter session set timezone = 'UTC';``` then check your query again. If there is an offset then instead of UTC you set the timezone to the corresponding one.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way of knowing what the offset is from the result?

Comment: Actually, I expect it to be visible if you select from your table, eg. ```select created_at from my_table limit 1``` then it should be like ```2023-08-03 18:01:00.000 -0700``` where the last part is your offset. Can you show us an example of the exact value stored in your table?

Comment: 2023-08-01 23:19:17.000 +0000

Comment: did it work after you do ```alter session set timezone = 'UTC';``` ?

Comment: Nope still doesn't want to know sadly :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for extracting only date irrespective of the timezone.

This works for me:

```
set dt = '2023-08-02 00:59:59';

select regexp_substr($dt, '(\\d)+\-(\\d)+\-(\\d)+');
```

I get back:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR($DT, '(\\D)+\-(\\D)+\-(\\D)+')
2023-08-02
```

More on regexp_substr [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr).

***Update***: after a second thought you don't even need a regex, just a cast to string first then to_date should work, like this:

```
select to_date(ended_at::string) from citibike_trips limit 10;
```

Comment: Still returns as '2023-08-01' to me

Comment: Cast the TIMESTAMPTZ value to string first before applying the regex. So I would expect this to work: `select regexp_substr(col::string, '(\\d)+\-(\\d)+\-(\\d)+');`

Comment: Still not am still getting the 2023-08-01

Comment: What is the col value you are passing to?

Comment: 2023-08-02 00:19:17.000
Even straightforward convert to string returns 2023-08-02 23:19:17.0000

Comment: This test works for me: `create or replace table test_t (t timestamp_tz);
insert into test_t values ('2023-08-02 00:19:17.000');
select * from test_t;
select t::string from test_t;
select to_date(t::string) from test_t;`. I get `2023-08-02` back.

Comment: I think this is likely because you are posting in and querying from the same timezone. My data has been posted as -2 from myself meaning any conversion is passing through

Comment: The value that you would see in UI when you cast the column to string is the one that would get the date extracted from. It's all based on your session timezone at that time.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't

Comment: So let me get this right: you are inserting `2023-08-02 00:19:17.000 -0200` and when you cast to string you get `2023-08-02 23:19:17.000`? I am confused how it would be possible to shift 23hours.

Comment: No, after the conversion it returns 2023-08-01 23:19:17.000. I need it to stay as the 2023-08-02

Comment: Are you sure the column is TIMESTAMPTZ or not other TIMESTAMP, like TIMESTAMP_LTZ? Maybe show a `select get_ddl('table', 'tablename');`

Comment: Definitely Timestamp_TZ

Answer (score 0):

So if you can strings with timezone information in them, then depending how you handle them, you will get different results.

If I have a set of time string, can parse them as no_timezone, or with timezone,  and or convert them to UTC, and then truncate them to date, I get different results:

```
with date_values as (
    select 
        try_to_timestamp_tz(column1) as c_tz
        ,try_to_timestamp_ntz(column1) as c_ntz
        ,CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', c_tz) as c_utc
    from values
    ('2023-08-01 00:00:00.001 -0100'),
    ('2023-08-01 00:00:00.002 +0000'),
    ('2023-08-01 23:19:17.003 +0000'),
    ('2023-08-01 23:19:17.004 +0400'),
    ('2023-08-01 23:19:17.005 -0400')
)
select *
    ,c_tz::date as c_tz_d
    ,c_ntz::date as c_ntz_d
    ,c_utc::date as c_utc_d
from date_values
```

[image]

which shows if you values have a timeszone component, you should use timezone_tz, to keep that value, and then convert to a unified timezone (I choose UTC because I like it the most). And then filter in that thus:

something like `WHERE c_utc::date = '2023-08-01'::date` should be used.